# Docker redis backup

Tags: docker

I am looking at this example

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from myredis -v $(pwd)/backup:/backup debian cp /data/dump.rdb /backup/
```

from Using Docker book.

Why do we need --rm flag?

Why do we have --volumes-from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is that

- you have a redis container named `myredis` which has some `volumes` for persistent storage (that you'd like to backup).
- you run a temporary `debian` container that will save the backup to `your_current_dir/backup` and get removed.

---

1. `docker run --rm ... debian` runs the container and removes it after it exits
2. `--volumes-from myredis` this way the `debian` container will have access to the database
3. `-v $(pwd)/backup:/backup` this second volume is used to put the backup at your current dir `$(pwd)/backup`. If it wasn't used, the backup would have only been copied to `/backup` (inside the container) and later been removed together with the container. This way the backup persists.
4. `cp /data/dump.rdb /backup/` copies the actual files

Comment: (Nowadays) you can achieve the same with https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Answer (score 1):

The `--rm` flag tells Docker Engine to remove the container once it exits. Without this flag, you need to manually remove the container after you stop it.

The `--volumes-from` flag mounts all the defined volumes from the referenced containers, it ensures the two containers mounts same volumes.